# Star-San smells like Windex

Tags: starsan

I have a spray bottle filled with a diluted Star-San solution that I used infrequently. Now I'm back to using it on a regular basis and it has a strong scent that is reminiscent of Windex.

Is it still safe to use? Could it just be reacting with the plastic of the bottle? The bottle is a standard all-purpose HPDE sprayer which should be fine.

Edit: It's about a year old and the pH is reading quite high at 7-8.

Comment: Windex has a strong ammonia smell, I've never gotten that from StarSan, nor is there anything in StarSan that could smell like ammonia.  Strange.

Comment: I think Starsan isn't really Starsan if the pH is over 4.

Comment: Someone in the household cleaned windows...

Answer (score 1):

Star-san does **not** smell like Windex.

I would not use it in a food and/or beverage environment. Even if it is "safe" to use, it could still impart a nasty flavour or aroma.  You've probably put a lot of effort into making your beverage, why risk ruining it for the sake of 20 cents worth of sanitiser in a cheap plastic bottle.

Dilute Star-San should be crystal clear, and have a pH under 3.5.  Five Star Chemicals (makers of Star-San) recommend diluting a new batch *every time*.  The shelf life of the concentrate is 2 years, and there should be a date on the bottle.

That said, many home brewers use diluted Star San after the "immediate use", me included.  But I make a new batch after a week or so.